# How can I ferment in a corny keg under constant pressure?

Tags: fermentation, keg, corny-keg, pressure

I'm thinking about switching from fermenting (primary and secondary) in glass carboys to using Cornelius kegs. Specifically, I'd ferment a 5.5 gallon batch in a 10 gallon keg.

My goal is to ferment under pressure -- around 10 or 15 psi. Why? There's [some](http://www.professorbeer.com/articles/esters.html) anecdotal [evidence](http://www.brewery.org/brewery/library/EstFormAW0696.html) that fermenting under pressure reduces ester production which could help with lager fermentation. But mostly, the pressure would a) let me remove yeast and trub after a few days of fermentation, and b) let me transfer the finished, carbonated beer to a serving keg under pressure

How can I regulate the pressure of fermenting beer in a Cornelius keg?

I can image a setup where the gas in line (with the tube removed, perhaps) is connected to a blow-off tube with an in-line pressure regulator. The regulator would need to be adjustable, so I could dial in different pressures for different beers, and at different stages in the fermentation.

I'm not sure if such an in-line regulator exists. I also expect it would need to be resilient to moisture. Fermenting 5.5 gallons in a 10 gallon vessel, there's not much chance that liquid will end up in the blow-off tube, but I want to be prepared for it if it does happen.

Has anyone ever put together a setup like this? Can anyone foresee technical difficulties I haven't thought of?

Comment: Interesting idea.  But is hydrostatic pressure at the bottom of a 200bbl conical the same type of effect as gas pressure of built up CO2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into "spunding valves", either to buy or DIY.  Often used for natural carbonation, but it could be used to control primary fermentation pressure, as you suggest.

Comment: For reference, it has a parts list: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f163/my-first-spunding-valve-231048/

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll buy the two 10 gallon kegs for sale at the LHBS and turn them into fermenters.

Answer (score 5):

I've done just this for my last 30 batches or so. It's lovely, and I see no reason to go back. I fill the corny to the weld line, bubble some oxygen up through the liquid diptube, and then connect my spunding valve to the gas connect.

The spunding valve is just a pressure gauge and an adjustable pressure relief valve attached to a 1/4" stainless tee. To prevent its getting clogged with blowoff, I use an empty water-filter housing as a water trap. It sits between the corny and the release valve to catch any liquid that comes out the top.

Good luck! It's a great way to ferment.

Comment: Great idea about the water filter as a trap. Are you using a 10gal or 5gal corny to ferment in?

Comment: Just a five gallon. I use fermcap and usually get a small amount of blow-off. A ten gallon would give me a bit more breathing room, but I still end up with just a smidge under five gallons of finished product.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the setup?